# Windows batch file run php serve & gulp

Tags: batch-file, laravel, gulp, browser-sync

Every-time when I start working on a laravel project, I need to run `php artisan serve` to launch the virtual server, and then `gulp` which will run the gulp file with browser-sync that proxy the virtual server.

I am thinking to simplify the process with the batch file. But the problem is once it run the first command, it stop there. How can I get 2 commands called one after another with just a double click the batch file?

Comment: how about first gulp-ing and then serving ?

Comment: I got the same problem but I'm using gulp first and then some other bat commands but it all stops after the gulp command is used, nothing past that runs

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about the windows batch scripting so. hope this helps

Write a batch script that opens TWO terminal windows and the first one will run `php artisan serve` and the second will run `gulp`

you cant chain them like `php artisan serve && gulp` because 1) this dont work in windows 2) the first command will never end unless you hit ctrl+c